Направляющий вектор для прямой
Прямая задается уравнением:
(1+t, 2+t, 1)
Правильно, что:
x-1=y-2=z/0 ? 


Ну в общем-то никакое число не будет равно z/0 :) В целом, первая запись говорит, что x = 1+t, y = 2+t, z = 1, дальше из первых равенств выразить t, то получится t = x-1 = y-2, но z туда никак не воткнешь - потому что z константно, и никак не зависит от t, поэтому t из него нельзя выразить.

Направляющий вектор для этой прямой (1,1,0). Зачем вам нужна неуниверсальная  каноническая запись, если есть параметрическая?

Для расчета угла между прямой и плоскостью: https://ru.onlinemschool.com/math/library/analytic_geometry/plane_line/

Расчёт угла делается через скалярное произведение нормали и направляющего вектора. Это есть и по вашей ссылке. Притягивать сюда каноническое уравнение просто ни к чему.

Для вашей прямой, для всякого действительного числа t определена точка (x, y, z) на этой прямой, где
x = 1+t
y = 2+t
z = 1

Из первых двух уравнений вытекает, что для каждой точки (x, y, z) этой прямой естественно имеет силу уравнение
x-1 = y-2

т.к. для каждой точки (x, y, z) этой прямой существует такое действительное число (параметр) t, что первые 2 из 3 параметрических уравнений этой прямой будут одновременно исполняться.
Но координата z всегда будет равна 1, значит
x-1 = y-2 = z

т.е.
x-1 = y-2 = 1   

будет верно только для единственной точки этой прямой, именно для точки (2, 3, 1).
